# Функция mail не отправляет письмо

Tags: php, email

Здравствуйте, есть функция:

```
function sendMailAboutOrder($email){
    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Тема сообщения";
    $message = ' 
    <body> 
        <p>Ваш логин: '.$to.'</p>
    </body>';
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Вызывается она из экшена:

```
function saveorderAction()
    {

        $cart = isset($_SESSION['saleCart']) ? $_SESSION['saleCart'] : null;

        if (!$cart) {
            $resData['success'] = 0;
            $resData['message'] = 'Нет товаров для заказа';
            echo json_encode($resData);
            return;
        }
        $second_name = isset($_POST['second_name']) ? $_POST['second_name'] : '';
        $patronymic = isset($_POST['patronymic']) ? $_POST['patronymic'] : '';
        $index = isset($_POST['index']) ? $_POST['index'] : '';
        $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
        $phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : '';
        $adress = isset($_POST['adress']) ? $_POST['adress'] : '';

        //создаем новый заказ и получаем его ID
        $orderId = makeNewOrder($name, $phone, $adress, $second_name, $patronymic, $index);

        if (!$orderId) {
            $resData['success'] = 0;
            $resData['message'] = 'Ошибка создания заказа';
            echo json_encode($resData);
            return;
        }

        // сохраняем товары для созданного заказа
        $res = setPurchaseForOrder($orderId, $cart);
        $email = isset($_SESSION['user']['email']) ? $_SESSION['user']['email'] : 0;
        sendMailAboutOrder($email);

        // если успешно, то формируем ответ, удаляем данные корзины
        if ($res) {
            $resData['success'] = 1;
            $resData['message'] = 'Заказ сохранен';
            unset($_SESSION['$saleCart']);
            unset($_SESSION['cart']);
        } else {
            $resData['success'] = 0;
            $resData['message'] = 'Ошибка внесения данных для заказа № ' . $orderId;
        }
        echo json_encode($resData);
    }
```

Тестируется на локальном сервере, функция mail работает(проверено на подобных отправках писем в других вызовах)
вот она:

```
 <?php
    //папка в которую будем складывать почту
    define('DIR','c:/xampp/tmp/mails/');
    //получаем из потока тело письма
    $stream = '';
    $fp = fopen('php://stdin','r');
    while($t=fread($fp,2048))
    {
        if( $t===chr(0) )
            break;
        $stream .= $t;
    }
    fclose($fp);
    //Сохраняем в файл
    $fp = fopen(mkname(),'w');
    fwrite($fp, $stream);
    fclose($fp);
    //Функция присвоения имени файлу
    function mkname($i=0)
    {
        $fn = DIR.date('Y-m-d_H-i-s_').$i.'.eml';
        if ( file_exists($fn) )
            return mkname(++$i);
        else return $fn;
    }
```

Ошибок в логах нет. В PHPStorm при просмотре работы кода(Debug(зеленый жучок в панели инструментов)), он заходит в функцию sendMailAboutOrder, и на последней строке выходит из проверки, т.е. непосредственно когда вызывается: `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`, дальше уже не проверяет.
Подскажите почему письма не приходят? ошибок шторм не подчеркивает, все норм вроде...

Comment: Для отправки почты нужен почтовый сервер, все что делает mail это подсоединяется к нему и отдаёт команду для отсылки. Читайте как настроить связь с сервером.

Comment: Повторюсь, есть 2 аналогичные функции, они корректно работают, только у них другие параметры и вызываются они в других контроллерах,мне же необходимо вызвать в этом контроллере. 
При просмотре как выполняется код, функция mail это последнее что делает сервер, потом ни чего не выполняется, хотя есть еще дальнейший код...

Comment: Может быть вы используете open server и письма кладутся в файл?

Comment: На локальном сервере письма не будут отправлены? Они сохраняются в отдельной папке

Comment: Хороший программист проверяет, что возвращает функция `mail`. И в случае `false` бьёт алярм

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы письма отправлялись из функции mail - необходимо настраивать почтовый сервер.

Чтобы его не настраивать и отправлять - можно использовать SMTP. Скачали библиотеку, зарегистрировали аккаунт на гугле или яндексе, или в другом месте - и установили настройки в библиотеку SMTP.

[Класс для отправки почты SMTP с примером](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: письма отправляются из других контроллеров, именно в этом не работает!!!! Ваш ответ не актуален!

Comment: @АнтонКутепов значит ошибки смотрите в логах почтового сервера, с которого у Вас отправляются письма. Пхп может отработать функцию (передать на исполнение почтовому серверу) - а почтовый сервер в свою очередь записывает логи

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет ошибок в коде `php`, просто сервер не настроен.

Нужно либо отправлять письма через `smtp` авторизацию на стороннем сервере, чтобы письма уходили с него, либо настраивать текущий: `PTR`, `SPF`, `DKIM`, `DMARC`. После чего письма будут приходить.